# When import package to use it in Jupyter Notebook with function saved in .py file in Python?

Tags: python, function, import, python-import

I have in Jupyter Lab functions.py file with function which I wrote which use package statsmodels as sm like below:

```
def my_fk():
  x = sm.Logit()
  ...
```

Then I import function from my file in Jupyter Notebook like below and I import needed package statsmodels:

```
import functions as fck
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

But when I try to use function imported from my file in Jupyter Notebook like below:

```
fck.my_fk()
```

I have an error like follow: `NameError: name 'sm' is not defined`

My question is:
Where should I import package `import statsmodels.api as sm` needed to run my function, so as to be able to use it in Jupyter Notebook ? In Jupyter Notebook or in .py file where I save my function ?

Comment: Did you import `statsmodels.api as sm` in your functions.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did on my jupyter cell

```
!pip install statsmodels
```

I was able to `import statsmodels.api as sm` successfully

Comment: Please suggest using current best practices. The magic command `%pip install` was added recently to insure that installations occur in the environment backing the running kernel associated with the notebook. The exclamation point alone doesn't insure that will be the case, as covered in the top paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). To avoid issues the use of the exclamation point alone can cause the modern `%pip install` (and related `%conda install` commands were added, ...

Comment: <continued>  see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about those modern magic commands.